# Prevent duplicated exception raising when using python decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

If I have a decorated function which raises an exception which is then caught in the decorator, in order to perform some logic. How can I still have the decorated function return the exception (without raising it again in the decorator).

DECORATED FUNCTION EXAMPLE:

```
    @ach_api_error()
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):

      profile = request.user.profile

      if not pk:
        raise CustomNotFoundException(detail="Not Found.")

      return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

DECORATOR EXAMPLE:

```
def ach_api_error():
  def decorate(f):
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        except CustomNotFoundException:
           #
           # PERFORM SOME EXCEPTION LOGGING HERE
           #
           raise CustomNotFoundException(detail="Not Found.")
    return applicator
  return decorate
```

I want the `decorate()` function to return the exception. How can I achieve this without raising the same exception twice?

Comment: Just change `raise` line in the `applicator` function, to `return`

Comment: @nima this will just result in this error:

```Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'api.v6.exceptions.CustomNotFoundException'>```